# Use Razor @Html.DisplayFor to display list of data separated by comma

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

How to use @Html.DisplayFor(...) to display a list of data, separated by comma.

For example,
Model:

```
public class Player
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<int> scores { get; set; }
}
```

If player.scores contains data 8,9,10.

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.scores);
```

Output will be like: 8910;

Is it possible to display the data separated by comma, like 8,9,10 ?

Comment: Try joining the elements of scores array like: @Html.DisplayFor(model => string.Join(",", model.scores));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point using `@Html.DisplayFor(...)` in your case (and it cannot work anyway because an expression cannot contain a method to convert the value).

`DisplayFor()` is useful when you are using a custom `DisplayTemplate`, or you have a `[DisplayAttribute]` applied to the property (and the property is `DateTime` or a numeric type which you want to format in a particular way).

If you do want to use `DisplayFor()`, then you must add another property to your view model, say

```
public string Score { get; set; }
```

and in the GET method you would set its value by using

```
model.Score = String.Join(", ", model.scores);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Score)
```

Alternatively, you can just use

```
@String.Join(", ", model.scores)
```

in the view directly (no `DisplayFor()`)